# Integrating Owl Carousel into the Wordrpess

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, owl-carousel

mates, I can't integrate Owl Carousel into my Wordpress site. I don't see a carousel on my page. Thanks!

My functions.php code:

```
function templatename_add_owlcarousel() {
wp_enqueue_script ( 'jquery' );

wp_enqueue_script( 'owlcarousel', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'owl-carousel', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/owl.carousel-init.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
wp_enqueue_style( 'owlcarousel-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/owl.carousel.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'owlcarousel-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/owl.theme.default.min.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'templatename_add_owlcarousel' );
```

owl.carousel.init.js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

      autoPlay: 3000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds

      items : 4,
      itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
      itemsDesktopSmall : [979,3]

  });

});
```

index.php part with a code:

```
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="item"><h1>1</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>2</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>3</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>4</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>5</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>6</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>7</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>8</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>9</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>10</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>11</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>12</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>13</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>14</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>15</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>16</h1></div>
</div>

<div class="customNavigation">
  <a class="btn prev">Previous</a>
  <a class="btn next">Next</a>
  <a class="btn play">Autoplay</a>
  <a class="btn stop">Stop</a>
</div>
```

My file structure is:

**templatename/assets/css/**

- owl.carousel.css
- owl.carousel.min.css
- owl.theme.default.min.css

**templatename/assets/js/**

- owl.carousel.min.js
- owl.carousel.js
- owl.carousel-init.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is your footer.php code? Didn`t you forget to put your initial code into your footer.php file?

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/owl.carousel-init.js"></script>

<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');>/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: In your case: `<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/js/owl.carousel-init.js"></script>

<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');>/assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'owlcarousel-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/owl.carousel.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'owlcarousel-style', get_template_directory_uri. '/assets/css/owl.theme.default.min.css' );
```

the problem is you put the same handle name for the both css file